# Cloudkit Private Database not showing up

Tags: xcode, icloud, cloudkit

I enabled Cloudkit in Xcode for the app I am working on, I signed into Icloud account in the simulator. The private database option is not showing in the Cloudkit dashboard. I can only select the public database, I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

**This is what it looks like**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to login to the dashboard with the same account that is used on device/simulator. You cannot access private DB of other users.